# Check if List Contains Items From Another List

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I realize versions of this have been asked before, but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for. I have two lists. I want to only print the items from otherList that do *not* contain items from firstList.

```
firstList = ["ABC", "DEF"]
otherList = ["ABCfoo", "foobar", "DEFfoo", "otherFooBar"]

matching = [s for s in otherList if "ABC" not in s] #Not sure how to apply this to multiple strings in a list
```

Desired result:

```
["foobar", "otherFooBar"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
matching = [el for el in otherList if not any(substr in el for substr in firstList)]
```

You could write `not any(substr in el ...)` as `all(substr not in el ...)` if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: Worked perfectly and easy to understand. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 2):

make a copy and remove elements

```
>>> matching = otherList.copy()
>>> for a in firstList:
...     for b in matching:
...             if a in b:
...                     matching.remove(b)
... 
>>> matching
['foobar', 'otherFooBar']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex,

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(firstList)
matching = [word for word in otherList if not re.search(pattern, word) ]

['foobar', 'otherFooBar']
```